# Error while deploying Angular 7 app on AWS S3 using codepipeline

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I want to deploy Angular 7 app(as static website) on S3 automatically using AWS Code pipeline.
I have created Angular app and pushed to my git repo.
I have created new AWS S3 bucket and created AWS Codepipline and integrated git repo

I am getting below error when aws code-pipelineb uilds the app:
**COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: ng build. Reason: exit status 1**

[image]

I am using buildspect.yml file

```
version: 0.2

env:
    variables:
        S3_BUCKET: "<bucket name>"
        BUILD_ENV : "prod"

phases:
    install:
        runtime-versions:
            nodejs: 10
        commands:
            # install dependencies
            - echo Installng source NPM dependencies...
            - npm install npm@latest -g
            - npm install -g @angular/cli

    pre_build:
        commands:
            - echo Prebuild steps
            - npm install

    build:
        commands:
            # Builds Angular application. You can also build using custom environment here like mock or staging
            - echo Build started on `date`
            - ng build

    post_build:
        commands:
            # Clear S3 bucket.
            - aws s3 rm s3://${S3_BUCKET} --recursive
            - echo S3 bucket is cleared.
            # Copy dist folder to S3 bucket, As of Angular 6, builds are stored inside an app folder in distribution and not at the root of the dist folder
            - aws s3 cp dist s3://${S3_BUCKET} --recursive
            - echo Build completed on `date`

artifacts:
    files:
        - '/'
    discard-paths: yes
    base-directory: 'dist*'
```

I feel that code-build environment is not properly configured. I mean Nodejs and npm is not installed correctly. Please go through above yml file and help me identify if I am missing anything.

Comment: This is a bit of a guess, but try changing `ng build` to `npm run build` in your yml build step.

Comment: Tried that. But not working. same kind of error : COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: npm run build. Reason: exit status 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This yml file worked perfectly fine for me :

```
version: 0.2

env:
    variables:
        S3_BUCKET: "pratik-portfolio"
phases:
install:
    runtime-versions:
        nodejs: 10
    commands:
    - echo $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
    - npm install -y npm@latest
    - npm install -g @angular/cli
    - rm package-lock.json
pre_build:
    commands:
    - npm install
build:
    commands:
    - echo build started on `date`
    - ng build
    - ls -l -F
post_build:
    commands:
            # Clear S3 bucket.
            - aws s3 rm s3://${S3_BUCKET} --recursive
            - echo S3 bucket is cleared.
            - aws s3 cp dist/{Your app name} s3://${S3_BUCKET} --recursive
            - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
    files:
        - '/'
    discard-paths: yes
    base-directory: 'dist*'
cache:
paths:
    - node_modules/
```

Comment: 've been trying to do this and sadly each time I add an artifact definition in my buildspec.yml I get CLIENT_ERROR: no matching artifacts paths found. what am I missing? which should be the artifact definition inside my project build to allow place all files inside my s3 bucket.

Comment: Can you share your buildspec.yml?

Comment: Sure I can: 
`version: 0.2
env:
    variables:
        S3_BUCKET: "myBucket-ui"
APP_NAME: "myBucket-ui"
BUILD_ENV : "prod"`

Comment: `phases:
    install:
        runtime-versions:
          nodejs: 10
        commands:
          - apt-get install curl
          - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
          - apt-get install -y nodejs
          - apt-get update -y
          - apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
          - npm install -g @angular/cli
          - npm install`

Comment: `build:
    commands:
      - ng build --prod

post_build:
    commands:
      - aws s3 sync dist/ s3://myBucket-ui --delete`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the build environment in your Buildspec.yml file.

Add this piece in and check if this helps -

```
build:
    commands:
        # Builds Angular application. You can also build using custom environment here like mock or staging
        - echo Build started on `date`
        - ng build --${BUILD_ENV}
```

This works for me perfectly!

Comment: Ok. I will try. But when you say ‘This works for me perfectly’ does that mean you have exact same yml file?

Comment: It means, the build step that is included in my answer is from my yml file. And it works

Comment: I have tried that but still getting same error. Do you have any online turorial link which I can follow?

Comment: Can you share the build logs for the run? That might be helpful to figure out what's happening. Sorry I don't have any online links other than what you can google.